# Ubuntu Server Disk Error Messages

Tags: boot, server, disk

Can anyone offer any help with the error messages that my server that I use for running ZoneMinder is reporting. I have attached a screen shoot of the messages. An example of the types of message is:

```
exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
irq_stat 0x40000008
failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
cmd 60/08:98:98:30:12/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 4096 in
res 41/40:00:98:30:12/00:00:01:00:00/01 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
status: { DRDY ERR }
error: { UNC }
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 17969304 op0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

Prior to me getting the attached messages the server wouldn't boot and was reporting a different message. This message was along the lines of UNEXECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY and telling me what to run it on. I did this and it reported errors which I selected yes to repair. After this the server starts up but outputs the attached messages. Once logged in messages stop and although Linux appears to be OK ZoneMinder does not run.

Any help appreciated before I contemplate a rebuild. Please note I am a Linux novice so please keep things simple for me!

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mvZs.jpg)

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: "Media error" and "I/O error" are bad news. Replace your disk as soon as possible.

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem, probably a defective harddisk which must be replaced. If there is any valuable data on the disk, I suggest to connect it to a different computer and try to copy the data to a new disk using some data rescue software, e.g. `ddrescue` to copy the whole disk, then maybe `photorec` to recover files from the disk image copy.

Comment: Thanks for comments I received. Took on board that it was likely a disk failure so replaced disk and rebuilt server.